# Get latitude longitude from google maps itinerary

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I would like to know if someone can help me about this point.

I have a script based on google maps who calculate itinerary. I would like to know if it is possible to get an array of this itinerary with the latitude-longitude every 1 kilometer for example.
If the itinerary is 100 kilometers long, i'll get an array with 100 datas

- (latitude,longitude, 0)
- (latitude,longitude, 1)
- (latitude,longitude, ...)
- (latitude,longitude, 99)

I need it because i would like to propose points interest near an itinerary. 
Example: https://roadtrippers.com/

1. You select the start of your trip
2. You select the destination of your trip
3. It suggest what you can do near your itinerary

Answer (score 1):

The DirectionsService class will give you a response with a [DirectionsResult object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult). This object has a property called `overview_path` that gives, from the docs:

> An array of LatLngs representing the entire course of this route. The
>   path is simplified in order to make it suitable in contexts where a
>   small number of vertices is required (such as Static Maps API URLs).

You can use these to perform places searches (with the [places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)) to get points of interest, etc, within a radius from each LatLng that's returned in the `overview_path` array.

Example:

```
var request = {
  origin: start_point,
  destination: end_point,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var path = (response.routes[0].overview_path);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its exactly what i need.

Just a question: you get your points of interest via a php-mysql script ?

Thank you

Comment: No, I used the places library. It's all exposed in the js. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: Ok, do you think that its possible to use it with a database who contains points of interest (name, latitude, longitude). Thank you, Claire

Comment: Yes. The `overview_path` is an array of Google Map's LatLng objects. You can use them however you need to. Take a look at this, it should get you started: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Comment: I have some difficulties to use the overview_path with a php mysql script. Do you have an exemple ? Thank you in advance

Comment: No, I don't have an example